# property 'filter' does not exist on type 'observable<any>'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

When trying to compile, i get the error

```
property 'filter' does not exist on type 'observable<any>'
```

after searching a bit, i found the recommendation to insert

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter'
```

after this, i get the same error, but for sort

```
property 'sort' does not exist on type 'observable<any>'
```

So, i removed the sort, and then i get the following error:

```
Type 'Observable<any> is not assignable to type 'any[]'. Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Observable<any>.
```

The information is imported from a json file

Part of the code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserinfoService } from '../services/userinfo.service';
import { Member } from '../class/member';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { MemberdialogComponent } from '../memberdialog/memberdialog.component';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-teammembers',
    templateUrl: './teammembers.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./teammembers.component.css']
})

export class TeammembersComponent implements OnInit
{

//props
teamMembers: any[];
searchQuery: any = "";
searchResults: any[] = this.teamMembers;
teams: any[];
selectedTeam: any;

//constructor
constructor(private userinfoService: UserinfoService, public dialog: MatDialog)
{
    //getData
  this.teamMembers = userinfoService.getMembers()
    .filter(member => member.isActive)
    .sort((a, b) => a.lastName.localeCompare(b.lastName));

    //put all information in results
    this.searchResults = this.teamMembers;

    //getTeams
    this.teams = this.teamMembers
        .map(item => item.team)
        .filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)
}
```

code for userinfoservice:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Member } from '../class/member';

@Injectable()
export class UserinfoService
{

    //constructor
    constructor(private http: Http)
    {

    }

    //methods or services

    getMembers()
    {
        return this.http.get('http://fakelocation/JsonData/api/teammembers').map(response => response.json())
    }
```

Comment: which version of rxjs you are using? and add code for the `UserinfoService`

Comment: What type is getMembers() returning?

Comment: getMembers()
    {
        return this.http.get('http://location/JsonData/api/teammembers').map(response => response.json())
    }

Answer (score 0):

As per RxJS 6.0 latest standard `https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md`, this issue case be resolve by piping the result of one operator to another.

```
this.teamMembers = userinfoService.getMembers()
    .pipe( .filter(member => member.isActive)
    .sort((a, b) => a.lastName.localeCompare(b.lastName)));
```